# $location.path changes path, does not navigate, but on refresh displays twice [Ionic]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to navigate to a page after successful login. Login page is a web page called via inappbrowser. Now, when inappbrowser successfully authenticates an user it should navigate to the view.

I used $location.path and it changes the path correctly. But, it doesnot show on device when it loads.( It shows correctly on Chrome though)

But, when i add a **window.location.reload(true)** statement, it loads the required page and then loads it again.

How do i stop is reloading twice?

```
.service('LoginService',function($q,$rootScope,$cordovaInAppBrowser,$http,$state,jwtHelper,$location) {
 return {
    loginUser: function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var promise = deferred.promise;
  $cordovaInAppBrowser.open(url).then(function(event) {     
    console.log(event);
     // success
  })
$rootScope.$on('$cordovaInAppBrowser:loadstop', function(e, event){
if(userIsValid){
deferred.resolve(username); //Here i validate the user and change the location
$location.path('app/playlists');
               }
}

promise.success = function(fn) {
            promise.then(fn);
            return promise;
        }
        promise.error = function(fn) {
            promise.then(null, fn);
            return promise;
        }
        return promise;
    }
}
```

Now, in app.js

```
 .state('app.playlists', {
  url: '/playlists',
  views: {
    'menuContent': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/playlists.html',
      controller: 'PlaylistsCtrl'
    }
  }
})
```

Now, in LoginController

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope,$timeout,$rootScope,LoginService,  $ionicPopup, $state,$location) {
$scope.login = function() {       
    LoginService.loginUser().success(function(data) {
        console.log(data);           
}).error(function(data) {
        var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
            title: 'Login failed!',
            template: 'Please check your credentials!'
        });
    });

}
```

})
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be using the `window.location.reload`. You should be including the $location module and performing a `$route.reload()` which resets your state router. You could also attempt to use `$state.reload();`     `$state.go($state.current, {}, {reload: true});`

I know there is a problem with IONIC Caching when it comes to route based navigation check this out `$ionicConfigProvider.views.maxCache(0);` It should be added where IONIC Is configured.

Comment: Not working.. it goes into the playlists controller, so,i placed $state.go($state.current, {}, {reload: true}); in playlists controller, but not working( No errors) . Does ionic support $route dependency , i was not able to inject it..Would really appreciate any test program

Comment: Ionic caching acts a little weird. Try to add the `$ionicConfigProvider.views.maxCache(0)` to your ionic config file. Can I see the view you are using for this @SouravDas

Comment: You were right. The issue was with the InAppBrowser, i didnt close it :P